# Using jsonwebtoken in Angular causes Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: angular, jwt

I would like to use the
**jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, [options, callback])** method of **jsonwebtoken** npm but I get errors constantly

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js (index.js:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js (sign-stream.js:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/jws/index.js (index.js:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/decode.js (decode.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
```

I read lot about this problem, adding this :

```
polyfills.ts
(window as any).global = window;
```

throws new error

```
psSupported.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at Object../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/lib/psSupported.js (psSupported.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js (verify.js:6)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js (index.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:95)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
```

(I saw several example e.g express-jsonwebtoken but they are pure js I have no too much experience adding complete js libs to Angular project.)

Is there any way fixing this problem or having any alternative using jsonwebtoken like sign method from another lib under Angular 8.0 ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to sign tokens in your frontend Angular app? This is normally done on the backend…

Comment: yes, its just a simulation of login, not for production, but important and i cant imagine how such a case can undermine this small work, unbelievable ...

Comment: But you don’t sign tokens in the front end.

Comment: its just simulate an third party login, but I solved with googling and finding many hacky solution

Comment: Out of curiosity, if it's for simulation, why are you signing actual tokens as opposed to using placeholder strings?

Comment: boss wanted to this ...

Answer (score 0):

in the end I can use jsonwebtoken in Angular 8.

Here comes what I did, Im not sure what they do but I would like to help for others take them a bit closer, if they get continuous errors.

This list was inspired by errors on console about
streams, crypto, global, buffer, process etc.

Install

```
    crypto-js
    stream
```

Writing some extra lines into default js files:

```
    browser.js
    node:  { crypto: true, stream: true },

    polyfills.js
    import { global } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';

    (window as any).global = window;
    global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
    (window as any).process = {
        env: { DEBUG: undefined },
    };
```

Configurations:

```
    tsconfig.app.json
      "paths": {
        "stream": ["../node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js"],
        "crypto": ["../node_modules/crypto-js"]
      }

    tsconfig.json
        "paths": {
          "stream": ["../node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js"],
          "crypto": ["../node_modules/crypto-js"
          ]
      }
```

All in all, it works now.

Csaba